# What is the best way to analyze free space in a postgres database and the grow of usage?

Tags: postgresql, monitoring, tablespaces

In Oracle you can in datadictinary analyze free space by using SQL like:

```
select
   b.tablespace_name, b.file_id, b.file_name, b.bytes/1024 total_KBytes,
   sum(a.bytes)/(1024) sum_free_Kbytes, max(a.bytes/(1024)) max_free_Kbytes
from sys.dba_free_space a, sys.dba_data_files b
where a.file_id = b.file_id
group by b.tablespace_name, b.file_id, b.file_name, b.bytes
order by b.tablespace_name;
```

How can I do this in postgres? What are the best tools to view and monitor database space in postgres?

Comment: You can do a `df -h` in your OS, then, for example, `\l+` from `psql` and compare what you find.  I, as a PostgeSQL guy, have no idea what `sys.dba_free_space` reports, though.

Comment: In Oracle there are files to store data. The view sys.dba_free_space contain information about size of such files and usage of filespace for data storage.

Comment: Just a followup to the previous: you can write a `pl/pythonu` function, for example, to achieve it in a single function call.  You'll need superuser rights for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Postgres' tablespace concept is **completely** different to Oracle's. Postgres doesn't use container files the way Oracle does. Each table is stored in one or more individual files. A tablespace is essentially just a directory where files are stored. It is **not** container file like in Oracle.

If a table gets dropped or truncated the space is immediately released on the file system level.

For a single **table** you could measure the size of the file(s) on disk and the actual size of the data which can deviate substantially depending on the write pattern of the application. This is caused by Postgres' implementation of MVCC.

The Postgres Wiki has several queries to investigate that: 
https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Show_database_bloat

Answer (score 1):

I am batteling with the same situation. I could previously select tablespace sizes, free-space and more in Oracle but now I am stuck.

It appears that this functionality is quite limited in PostgreSQL. Notice how I had to Zero (0) out all the missing data in below query...

```
select spcname tablespacenme,  
       0 as megs_free, 
       0 as megs_alloc, 
       pg_tablespace_size(spcname) as megs_used, 
       0 as Pct_Free, 
       0 as Pct_used, 
       0 as max_space 
from pg_tablespace
```

Maybe you find something on this document:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBSIZE

Good luck

Comment: A tablespace in Postgres is technically something completely different then a tablespace in Oracle. In Postgres it's not a container file that contains everything, it's essentially only a directory name. So on the database level there is no such thing as "free space" inside a tablespace. There is only "free space" on the file system where the directory is located.